# How can I add onClickListener in Materialviewpage Adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, material-design, adapter

I am using this library from github: https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager. I want the diffrent card views to open  diffrent activities. How can I achieve it?

I couldn"t find any solution in wiki there

TestRecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class TestRecyclerViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

List<Object> contents;

static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
static final int TYPE_CELL = 1;

public TestRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Object> contents) {
    this.contents = contents;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        default:
            return TYPE_CELL;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contents.size();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = null;

    switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE_HEADER: {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_card_big, parent, false);
            return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
            };
        }
        case TYPE_CELL: {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_card_small, parent, false);
            return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
            };
        }
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case TYPE_HEADER:
            break;
        case TYPE_CELL:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why you didn't create a custom ViewHolder?

Comment: I tried but doesn't seems to be my cup of tea,Some help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well,
if you don't want to implement a custom viewHolder you can do something like this in the `onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)`:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        //start which activity you want
    }
})
```

Otherwise you can implement a custom ViewHolder. Here is a guide: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: thank you for answering, i found a way out with custom viewholder